# Dart: library and export for web apps

Tags: shared-libraries, dart, encapsulation, dependency-management, package-management

I am experimenting with my first Dart web app and do not expect to make any part of my app a reusable library for other apps/libs. As such, I do not have a `lib` directory in my project; rather, I have a `web` directory.

I guess my intent is to have my `web` directory look like this:

```
web/
    Main.dart <-- where my main method is
    logging/
        Logger.dart
        LogLevel.dart
    model/
        Signin.dart
        Signout.dart
    view/
        SigninView.dart
        signinView.html
    presenter/
        SigninPresenter.dart
    ...lots of other packages
```

Several questions:

1. Should my entire application (everything under `web`) be considered to be a part of the same `library`? If so, would I then put `library myapp;` at the top of every Dart file? Otherwise, what is the level of granularity for a `library`? Should I put it package-level, and have `Logger` and `LogLevel` inside `library logging;`? Is it at the class/file level and have a `library logger` and a `library log_level`?
2. Is my `web` directory set up correctly? I'm coming from Java so I'm treating `web` the same as Java/Maven's `src/main/java` directory, and setting up a package structure under `web` that makes sense to me...
3. I understand that the `import` keyword is for importing source types from other packages. But what about `export` - what does that do?

Comment: Please, keep one question per post instead of spawning several at once.

Comment: Thanks @Braiam (+1) but that is always a judgement call.  I feel like if you have several, similar questions, and they all require the same setup/backstory/SSCCE, that it's better to just group them into one question rather than bog SO down with the extra text from multiple questions.

Comment: SO is not a forum, no one feels bogged, also your question should be searchable, if I need to know what `export` does in dart sources, how can I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20789600/792066) question? And if you ask several questions in one post is more likely that yours will be closed as duplicated just because it answers one of your many questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you have a `lib/` directory and put shared code within it. If the code isn't directly to be used by other parts of your app, move that code to the `src/` directory within `lib/`.  I realize that you are not planning to make your app reusable by other apps, but code which is consumed by different parts of *your* app should probably live within `lib/`.

A lot of this is a matter of convenience and convention, but I try to keep my `web/` directory pretty lean, even going so far as to place only those `.dart` files in it that are directly referenced in a `.html` file. Your mileage may vary, but I find that this convention (putting shared code in `lib/` and web-specific code in `web/` helps keep things clear).

As for library directives, I like to use a single namespace which is the same as the name of the app.

So, a library in `lib/models.dart` could be declared like this:

```dart
library myApp.models;
```

A library in `web/foo/bar.dart' could be declared like this:

```dart
library myApp.web.foo.bar;
```

Comment: Thanks @Shailen Tuli (+1) - very sound advice. I guess I'm confused over the **purpose** of the library. What's the difference between placing `web/foo/bar.dart` in a library named `myapp.web.foo.bar` or putting it in one called `myapp.web.foo`? What are the benefits/cons to either approach? Thanks again!